# I need table name with prefix in custom controller file. [magento 2]

Tags: magento2, database, prefix

```
public function checkHelpful($rid ,$pid ,$uid )
{
    $connection = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $tbl = $connection->getTableName('catalog/product_index_price');
    echo $table;
}
```

the output of this is 'catalog/product_index_price'. Not getting the exact table name with prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this issue, instead of using this

```
$connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
```

We have to use this :

```
$connection  = $this->_resource; OR

$connection = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 protected $_resource;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{

    $connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    $tableName   = $connection->getTableName('tablename_without_prefix'); // It will return table with prefix

    $mapsDeleteQuery = "your raw SQL Query";
    $connection->query($mapsDeleteQuery);
}
```

Comment: I implemented the same thing, but its giving me the same result as previous (table name without prefix).